# Integration of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{(\lambda +is)t}-e^{-(\lambda +is)t}}{e^{\pi t}-e^{-\pi t}}dt$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Integration of $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{(\lambda +is)t}-e^{-(\lambda +is)t}}{e^{\pi t}-e^{-\pi t}}dt$$

I am thinking about this integral from last half and hour but still can't figure it out how to solve this. what i was think is to make this in form

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh(\lambda+is)t}{\sinh (\pi t)} dt$$ but still this will get me nowhere. please just give me a hint how to proceed this.

Thank you.

Comment: You may apply Complex Analysis to solve this integral, choosing a rectangular contour or you may write $\csch(πt)=\sum_0^\infty \exp\left(-π(n+1)t)\right)$ and then solve the resulting series after integrating.

Comment: @honey kumar This is a gentle reminder to please 'accept' an answer **if** your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An amusing way get the answer: first extend the integration range to $-\infty, \infty$. The integrand is even in $t$, so we get a $1/2$ factor up front. I'm taking $a=\lambda+is$.

$$ I(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \ \frac{e^{at}-e^{-at}}{e^{\pi t}-e^{-\pi t}}$$

The integrand has poles at $t=in$, $n \in Z $. The pole at $t=0$ is a removable singularity. An anticlockwise contour$^\dagger$ in the complex $t$ plane will enclose all the residues for $n=1,2,3,..$, which are in the upper half plane. Courtesy of the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we have

$$ I(a)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}R_n $$

$$ R_n = 2\pi i \lim_{t \rightarrow  in} (t-in) \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{at}-e^{-at}}{e^{\pi t}-e^{-\pi t}} $$

$$ R_n =-(-1)^n \sin{(na)} $$

The sum for $I(a)$ may be performed by writing $\sin$ in exponential form and doing the two geometric sums$^\ddagger$.

$$ R_n=-\frac{1}{2i}\left[ (-e^{ia})^n- (-e^{-ia})^n \right]$$

For which we get

$$ I(a)= -\frac{1}{2i} \left[ \frac{-e^{ia}}{1+e^{ia}} - \frac{-e^{-ia}}{1+e^{-ia}} \right]$$

After simplification, this yields

$$ I(a)= \frac{1}{2} \tan \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)$$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Clearly, this converges for $-\pi <a<\pi$ due to the nearest singularities in $\tan$ at $\pm \pi/2$.

$\dagger$ Along the real axis then closed in the upper plane.

$\ddagger$ As mentioned in the comments, these individual sums are divergent. Don't worry! Either we can sum $-(-1)^n \sin(na)$ directly, or regularize the individual sums. For instance, using [Euler summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation)

$$ E_1(x)= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n (-e^{ia})^n=\frac{xe^{ia}}{1+xe^{ia}}$$

$$ E_2(x)= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n (-e^{-ia})^n=\frac{x}{x+e^{ia}}$$

Which converge for $x$ sufficiently small. We then have

$$I(a)= \lim_{x \rightarrow1} (E_1(x)-E_2(x))$$

Which leads to the same answer.

Comment: The geometric series $\sum_{n\ge1}(-e^{\pm ia})^n$ don't converge because their $n$th terms don't have modulus approaching $0$, but you can get around this by e.g. summing each to $n=N$, then checking the difference has $n\to\infty$ limit.

Comment: Correction: even that doesn't work because$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N[(-e^{ia})^n-(-e^{-ia})^n]&=\frac{1+(-1)^Ne^{i(N+1)a}}{1+e^{ia}}-\frac{1+(-1)^Ne^{-i(N+1)a}}{1+e^{-ia}}\\&=\frac{1-e^{ia}+(-1)^N(e^{i(N+1)a}-e^{-i(N+1)a})}{1+e^{ia}}\\&=i\tan\frac{a}{2}+\frac{(-1)^N2i\sin(N+1)a}{1+e^{ia}}\end{align}$$doesn't have an $N\to\infty$ limit. Ultimately, your technique needs some regularization.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. I have edited the post to indicate how to sum the series individually.

Comment: You're welcome. Incidentally, that your edited-in regularization has the original integral as its limit is a use of dominated convergence to commute a limit with an integral operator.

Answer (score 3):

By 3.511.2 in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sinh (zt)}}{{\sinh (\pi t)}}dt}  = \frac{1}{2}\tan \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)
$$
provided $\left| z \right| < \pi$. Take $z=\lambda+is$.

Comment: thank you @Gary , but how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Considering $\displaystyle \mathcal{I}(\alpha, \beta) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\alpha z}{\sinh \beta z}\,\mathrm{d}z$, we show that $\displaystyle \mathcal{I}(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\pi}{2\beta} \tan\left(\frac{\alpha \pi}{2\beta}\right)$.

Then your integral is $\displaystyle \mathcal I(\lambda+is, \pi)$. Starting with   $z \mapsto \frac{1}{\beta} \log(z)$, we have:

\begin{aligned} \displaystyle \mathcal{I}(\alpha, \beta) & = \frac{1}{\beta} \int_0^1 \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} -z^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}}{z^2-1}\;{dz} \\& = \frac{1}{\beta} \int_0^{1} \left( z^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}-z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\right) \sum_{k \ge 0}z^{2k} \;{dz}\\& = \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{k \ge 0}\int_0^1 z^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+2k} -z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+2k}\;{dz} \\& = \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+2k}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+2k} \\& = \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{2\alpha /\beta }{(1+2 k)^2-(\alpha/\beta)^2}  \\& = \frac{1}{2\beta} \sum_{k ~ \text{odd} } \frac{4\alpha/\beta}{k^2-(\alpha/\beta)^2} \end{aligned}

Consider the series $\displaystyle \displaystyle \pi\cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z}+ \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{2z}{z^2-n^2} $. Map $\displaystyle z \mapsto \frac{z}{2} $ and divide by two then we have:
$\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z\right) = \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{z}{(z/2)^2-n^2} $$\displaystyle \displaystyle =  \frac{1}{z}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{4z}{z^2-(2n)^2} = \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n ~ \text{even}} \frac{4z}{z^2-n^2}$
Thus $\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{2z}{z^2-n^2} -\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n ~ \text{even}} \frac{4z}{z^2-n^2}$ $\displaystyle \displaystyle  =\pi\cot(\pi z)-\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{2}\right)$
Hence  $\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \textrm{ odd}} \frac{4z}{z^2-n^2} = -\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$ and so $\displaystyle  \displaystyle  \mathcal I(\alpha, \beta)=\frac{1}{2\beta} \sum_{k ~ \text{odd} } \frac{4\alpha/\beta}{(\alpha/\beta)^2-k^2} = \frac{\pi}{2\beta} \tan\left(\frac{\alpha \pi}{2\beta}\right).$